# Is it required to make a separate /boot partition for for multiple linux os installation?

Tags: linux, boot, partition, dual-boot

Is it required to make a separate /boot partition for for multiple linux os installation ?

Comment: You don't need `/boot` as a separate partition. If you choose to do this, though, you shouldn't share it across multiple installations.

Answer (score 0):

These days, you don't need a separate /boot partition for any major Linux distribution (and doing so can even cause some hassle).  If you try to run multiple Linux installations off of a single boot partition, you will most likely have trouble booting.  The best thing to do, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, is to have one swap partition for all your Linuxes, and then one ext3/4/BTRFS/whatever partition for each installation, where you'll put all your system and user files for each Linux installation.  You can have a separate data partition/drive, as needed, and mount it in each OS, as appropriate.

Comment: This is wrong, as far as I can tell. The default/recommended partitioning for every distribution I've tried (including Fedora) includes a separate `/boot`, and they usually try to arrange things such that you always boot from its single `/boot` partition and use the GRUB menu to select between dual-boot options, whose kernels and initrds all reside on the same `/boot`.

Comment: @TomHunt how, then, does `update-grub` distinguish between kernels & initrds for one distribution vs those for another distro?  os-prober expets to find kernels for different distros in different /boot directories.

Comment: Debian-based distributions don't use a seperate /boot, in my experience.  This includes Ubuntu and its derivatives.

GRUB distinguishes between different partitions via its command-line options and boots from the specified partition and file within that partition.  `update-grub` is going to automatically assume that all Linux kernels are meant to be booted by the operating system in which you wrote the configuration files via the `update-grub` command.  This will probably result in some unbootable GRUB entries.

Comment: I don't think you opening statement is correct. Separate boot partition is required when you have your root partition formatted as something exotic that grub can't handle (or not handle well). Eg Xfs or LUKS encrypted (grub doesn't handle large LUKS partitions well).  So you  use seperate /boot for even on Debian etc. historically they were popular because grub legacy couldn't handle large disk offsets, so /boot had to be at the beginning of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two rationales about the need for a `/boot` partition:

- the BIOS can't access sectors anywhere on a big disk,
- the bootloader can't load fancy disk manager or file systems used for `/`.

I guess that the first rationale is not true with nowadays systems. And with Grub2, even something like LVM or Btrfs can be loaded with the first stages (involving first sectors outside a file system).

However, in 2022, I failed to install Debian with a single `/ + /boot` volume. It was on a Cloud server, without much way to analyse what happended (I havn't the display on my sight of view).

Answer (score 0):

### Do you need a separate /boot partition for each Linux?

Each distribution will assume that it is the only thing modifying /boot (via `yum`, `apt`, ...). Don't let multiple distributions manage the same `/boot` **directory** (partition).  System upgrades will effectively fight one another over it.

If you dedicate a partition to /boot then each distribution typically needs its own.

### What is /boot?

*This is a poorly understood topic, be careful what you read*.  The /boot directory acts as a bridge allowing the running operating system to read and write the bootloader's configuration.  It's not there for anything else at runtime.

Think of /boot directory is a space to store the boot loader's configuration & plugins and the kernel & initramfs.

When you boot your system, the computer's firmware will kick off the boot loader and the boot loader will read /boot, load the configuration.  Then it will load the desired kernel and initramfs file.

In fact the only reason to keep it mounted in Linux under most normal circumstances is that system upgrade tools (invoked by `yum`, `apt`, ...) might expect it to be present so they can, for example, install a new kernel.  These tools are pretty inflexible. I am NOT advising you to run without a /boot directory.

### Does /boot need to be its own partition?

Frequently no.  The one good reason to put /boot on it's own partition is so that your systems root directory / can be stored on something the bootloader cannot read, or read well.

### Feeling very brave?

Actually yes you can share /boot by two mechanisms.  But I am NOT suggesting either of these are advisable.

#### Only one Linux installs a kernel & boot loader

Across distributions, Linux kernels can be surprisingly compatible.  At least those with a similar Major version can be.  It's therefore possible to have one distribution with no bootloader or kernel installed.  Such a setup should not try to modify /boot and will not put anything useful in even if it does.

You could therefore have one Linux manage all the boot entries for another and just share a Kernel between them.

#### Subdirectories

People don't commonly think of this, but it's quite safe to bind-mount something onto /boot.  By this mechanism you could have one partition containing a differently named boot directory for each install.

Your `/etc/fstab` would look something like this:

```
# Mount the boot partition
UUID=cb015492-4ca4-4fae-a416-6d89443e4680 /media/boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# Bind mount the desired 
/media/boot/ubuntu-jammy-boot /boot none bind 0 0
```

The last time I checked this, it looked like `grub-install` understood the arrangement and correctly configured grub's `grub.cfg` in EFI.  Eg: `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`.  If not then you can manually batch the the config line in this file:

```
set prefix=($root)'/ubuntu-jammy-boot/grub'
```